# ¿Alguien sabe como hacer este efecto?

Tags: html, css, web

Me gustaría saber si alguien puede ayudarme o sabe como hacer el efecto que tiene esta pagina web:
https://discover.areyouunstoppable.com/mission/

Hay un vídeo y cuando bajas, el vídeo salta arriba a la izquierda.

Alguien podría ayudarme o decirme como se puede conseguir eso?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías empezar tu búsqueda con los sticky menus, que hace un efecto similar pero con las barras de menú. Una vez entiendas eso, podrías buscar cómo trabajar con el reproductor del vídeo.